# Alternative keyboard layouts on iPadOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ipad, ipados, magic-keyboard-ipad

Whether with touchscreen keyboard or external Bluetooth keyboard, it is possible to select some alternative keyboard layouts. But is it possible to remap keys arbitrarily so as to support various layouts that are not supported in iOS out of the box? If not, are there any workarounds like by installing third party keyboards such as gBoard?

If not, would it not theoretically be possible to develop a third party installable keyboard for iOS or iPadOS which allows one to define custom input layouts? And would it be possible to extend this mapping to support external Bluetooth accessory type hardware keyboards?

Answer (score 1):

There are already a great many alternative screen keyboards available in the App Store from 3rd parties, plus whole systems for adding and making them like [Keyman](https://keyman.com/iphone-and-ipad/). But so far Apple has not provided any way for app makers to include custom hardware layouts.

(Unfortunately Keyman Developer is only a Windows app at present)

A list of hardware layouts provided by Apple as of iOS 11 can be found [here](https://thgewecke.github.io/mlingmac/ios11kbs.html). If anyone has a more recent one, please add a link.

Comment: Does this answer change at all once a device is kg jailbroken?

Comment: @JosephP. Sorry, no idea.  You might want to ask a separate question about what's possible under jailbreaking or look at this one  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263564/using-custom-hardware-keyboard-layout-on-ios?rq=1